# Where to ask about bulletproof glass?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the various materials used for bulletproof glass, their strengths and what they can stop but I'm not sure where to ask.

> In the TV show the 'The Punisher' is a scene where he attempt to kill a man standing at his window with a sniper. To his surprise the glass stops, what I assume is, a 50cal sniper shot. Based on a quick Google search it would take 3in of polycarbonate to stop that and a 1ft of tempered glass. The window in question definitely wasn't that thick so I'm wondering is there a material of which an inch or less could stop a 50cal sniper round or was that complete fiction?

I was thinking probably Physics or Engineering?

Comment: [tag:site-recommendation]: _"Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask"_

Comment: @jonrsharpe what further details should I provide?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is _include the question_, as a block quote. Then it's unambiguous what you're intending to ask.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you'd ask questions about bulletproof glass in general, but this particular question would actually be on-topic on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). Fundamentally, you're asking whether a plot element in a TV show (a relatively thin window being able to stop a 50cal sniper round) is realistic or not, and such questions are accepted there under the ["realism" tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to focus the question on whether a material exists that could be used for the purpose (it would not only have to have the physical properties, but be *transparent*, after all) - regardless of whether it's actually used for such in the real world - Physics.SE does make sense; there's a [material-science](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-science) tag. Engineering.SE does have a "materials" tag, but it's less popular and seems particularly focused on doing engineering calculations in practical rather than theoretical situations.

If you aren't asking this as a matter of movie realism, I would trim back the motivation section of the question and get right the point: is there a material with those properties?